# Connecting with Athena using Python and pyathenajdbc

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am trying to connect to AWS Athena using python. I am trying to use pyathenajdbc to achieve this task. The issue I am having is obtaining a connection. When I run the code below, I receive an error message stating it cannot find the AthenaDriver. ( java.lang.RuntimeException: Class com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver not found).  I did download this file from AWS and I have confirmed it is sitting in that directory.

```
from mdpbi.rsi.config import *
from mdpbi.tools.functions import mdpLog
from pkg_resources import resource_string
import argparse
import os
import pyathenajdbc
import sys

SCRIPT_NAME = "Athena_Export"

ATHENA_JDBC_CLASSPATH = "/opt/amazon/athenajdbc/AthenaJDBC41-1.0.0.jar"
EXPORT_OUTFILE = "RSI_Export.txt"
EXPORT_OUTFILE_PATH = os.path.join(WORKINGDIR, EXPORT_OUTFILE)


def get_arg_parser():
    """This function returns the argument parser object to be used with this script"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__, formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)

    return parser


def main():
    args = get_arg_parser().parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    logger = mdpLog(SCRIPT_NAME, LOGDIR)

    SQL = resource_string("mdpbi.rsi.athena.resources", "athena.sql")

    conn = pyathenajdbc.connect(
        s3_staging_dir="s3://athena",
        access_key=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secret_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        region_name="us-east-1",
        log_path=LOGDIR,
        driver_path=ATHENA_JDBC_CLASSPATH
    )
    try:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(SQL)
            logger.info(cursor.description)
            logger.info(cursor.fetchall())
    finally:
        conn.close()

    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rtn = main()
    sys.exit(rtn)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
>       exec code in run_globals   File "/home/ec2-user/jason_testing/mdpbi/rsi/athena/**main**.py", line 53,
>   in 
>       rtn = main()   File "/home/ec2-user/jason_testing/mdpbi/rsi/athena/**main**.py", line 39,
>   in main
>       driver_path=athena_jdbc_driver_path   File "/opt/mdpbi/Python_Envs/2.7.10/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyathenajdbc/**init**.py",
>   line 65, in connect
>       driver_path, **kwargs)   File "/opt/mdpbi/Python_Envs/2.7.10/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyathenajdbc/connection.py",
>   line 68, in **init**
>       jpype.JClass(ATHENA_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME)   File "/opt/mdpbi/Python_Envs/2.7.10/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_jclass.py",
>   line 55, in JClass
>       raise _RUNTIMEEXCEPTION.PYEXC("Class %s not found" % name)

Comment: if you are allowed to use something besides pyathenajdbc you can use athena directly from python (lowlevel): http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/athena.html, this gives you a more pythonic interface: https://github.com/laughingman7743/PyAthena

Comment: What is mdpbi, something created within your organisation? Is mdpbi.rsi is something to reduce 'repetitive strain injury' cased by typing too much SQL ?

Comment: It is part of code structure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JDBC driver requires Java 8. I was currently running Java 7. I was able to install another version of Java on EC2 instance.

https://tecadmin.net/install-java-8-on-centos-rhel-and-fedora/#

I had to also set the java version in my code. With these changes, the code now runs as expected.

```
from mdpbi.rsi.config import *
from mdpbi.tools.functions import mdpLog
from pkg_resources import resource_string
import argparse
import os
import pyathenajdbc
import sys

SCRIPT_NAME = "Athena_Export"


def get_arg_parser():
    """This function returns the argument parser object to be used with this script"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__, formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)

    return parser


def main():
    args = get_arg_parser().parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    logger = mdpLog(SCRIPT_NAME, LOGDIR)

    SQL = resource_string("mdpbi.rsi.athena.resources", "athena.sql")

    os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/opt/jdk1.8.0_121"
    os.environ["JRE_HOME"] = "/opt/jdk1.8.0_121/jre"
    os.environ["PATH"] = "/opt/jdk1.8.0_121/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/bin"

    conn = pyathenajdbc.connect(
        s3_staging_dir="s3://mdpbi.data.rsi.out/",
        access_key=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secret_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        schema_name="rsi",
        region_name="us-east-1"
    )
    try:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(SQL)
            logger.info(cursor.description)
            logger.info(cursor.fetchall())
    finally:
        conn.close()

    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rtn = main()
    sys.exit(rtn)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
    pyathenajdbc.ATHENA_JAR = ATHENA_JDBC_CLASSPATH
```

You won't be needing to specify the driver_path argument in the connection method

Comment: I have added pyathenajdbc.ATHENA_JAR = ATHENA_JDBC_CLASSPATH to code and commented out driver_path=ATHENA_JDBC_CLASSPATH in the connection call. I am thinking this may be a java version issue